# Escaping bad server paths for RSYNC via SSH

Tags: perl, ssh, escaping, rsync, non-ascii-characters

I have a client using the most ridiculous file/folder naming, and need to RSYNC their data to a NAS. My RSYNC logic is written in Perl, and quotemeta() worked well, until we had to deal with Danish characters.

See example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$my_string_a = "/data/stuff/folder K/ \snappy/SLE.T.TET/Div (erse)/SLETTET/Disk klæbere";
$my_string_b = quotemeta($my_string_a);
print "\n".$my_string_a."\n".$my_string_b."\n";
exit;
```

Outputs:

```
/data/stuff/folder K/ snappy/SLE.T.TET/Div (erse)/SLETTET/Disk klæbere
\/data\/stuff\/folder\ K\/\ snappy\/SLE\.T\.TET\/Div\ \(erse\)\/SLETTET\/Disk\ kl\�\�bere
```

Note: I have to use escape characters as ssh / rsync requires "double escaping" in Perl.

Is there a better canned solution or will I need to Regex my way past this?

Comment: Probably this bit from `perldoc -f quotemeta` applies to your case: "In Perl v5.14, all non-ASCII characters are quoted in
            non-UTF-8-encoded strings, but not quoted in UTF-8 strings.

            Starting in Perl v5.16, Perl adopted a Unicode-defined strategy
            for quoting non-ASCII characters; the quoting of ASCII
            characters is unchanged. ..."

Comment: You're doing something wrong/deceptive if you claim your script contains a non-ASCII char (e.g. `æ`), but you don't use `use utf8;`.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking if what you are doing is correct? To know that, we'd need to know what consumes the output of your script. It seems to me that String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote` should be involved if composing a command to execute remotely.

Comment: @ikegami I know my code is incorrect as its failing the rsync. Let me expand... I am receiving HTML encoded server paths, I need to use this supplied path in an rsync destination. Whats happening is my input path (e.g. $my_string_a) becomes $my_string_b in my rsync. Reading the comments I am assuming I need to do character encoding conversions to make it work?

Comment: No idea. Show your inputs precisely (e.g. using something `sprintf("%vX", $input)`), and as I mentioned above, identify how the outputs are used.

Comment: @Christian : _Is there a better canned solution or will I need to Regex my way past this?_ IMHO the answer is: NO. Not with quotemeta if you have to preserve some non ASCII chars. A simple regex escaping parens and whitespaces can be the best way, depending on the fantasy of your client.

Comment: We need to know precisely how you are passing the paths to rsync. If you are passing it through the shell (such as a string form system, backticks, or within a ssh command), quotemeta is the wrong tool, you should be using String::ShellQuote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl builtins invoking external programs (i.e. `system`, `exec`, etc.) don't always handle encodings correctly.

You can try using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) which has native support for transferring files with `rsync` and can handle automatic [quoting](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Shell-quoting) and [encoding](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Data-encoding) of the `rsync` command line for you.

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
use utf8;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(...,
                            argument_encoding => 'utf8');

$ssh->rsync_put("/data/stuff/folder K/ \snappy/SLE.T.TET/Div (erse)/SLETTET/Disk klæbere",
                $target_dir)
    or die "rsync_failed " . $ssh->error;
```